# F# Excel - error on new ApplicationClass

Tags: excel, f#

When I do just

```
type RExcel() = 
    let xlApp = new ApplicationClass()
```

I've got this Error :

> Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
>   failed due to the following error:
>   80040154 Класс не зарегистрирован  (Class doesn'registered)
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

So maybe I can realize Excel read/write functions some another way.

Added : installed OpenOffice... Version of assembler is 14 ... Maybe I need to use some another .NET library for Excel ?

Comment: Which office version is installed on your computer? And which version of the PIO Assemblies do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I correctly understand your scenario, but if you want to call Excep using `ApplicationClass`, you need to have full Excel installed on your machine (and all users of your application will need to install Excel too). The library is just a wrapper that calls some internal functionality in Excel.

If you want to generate Excel files in F# directly, you can take a look at libraries that generate XLSX (new XML-based format) files. For example: http://epplus.codeplex.com/ This should be easy to use from F# and should not have any other requirements.

Comment: I want to have ability use with 2003 and 2007 Excel documents